# How to compare current workingspace with previous commit in git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

Sometimes when I fix bugs, I need to compare current repo with a specific commit to see which files are being changed and overall features.

Using git history extension in vscode, I can only compare one file at a time with a specific commit but I want to view the entire repo changes. Currently, I soft reset to the commit I want to compare.

```
git reset --soft 13dbd96
```

Is there other ways in git or third party vscode extensions to use that is more efficient?

Comment: `git diff 13db96`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `git diff` command to compare. As [@evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76877609/how-to-compare-current-workingspace-with-previous-commit-in-git#comment135528070_76877609), you could use `git diff 13dbd96` for your example. You can also make use of navigations by looking at the paths to your different blobs.

For instance, you can see all differences between your current version and the version at `HEAD~2` by using the command, `git diff HEAD~2`.

Another thing: `git reset` can be a smart way to look at lists of files that changed between versions, but you'll probably want to make sure you have stashed your changes before changing the position of the HEAD a bunch of times. You don't want to accidentally do a hard reset and then lose your most recent changes.